# link-arg not passing compiler options to rustc

Tags: rust, asm.js

I'm generating asm.js from a Rust file like so:

```
rustc demo.rs --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten -C opt-level=0 -C link-arg="-s MINIMAL_RUNTIME=1" -C link-arg="-s ENVIRONMENT=web" -C link-arg="-s LEGACY_VM_SUPPORT=1" -o ../../build/bytecode/demo.asm.js
```

However, when I look through the generated asm.js file, I can clearly see that those compiler options were not passed through - the code still assumes it can be run in any environment, and the legacy VM polyfills are missing.

What am I missing?

This is the rust file, in case that matters:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn my_add(num1: f64, num2: f64) -> f64 {
    return num1 + num2;
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("Rust loaded");
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `-s` ? Any documentation that is reffering to this flag ?

Comment: @VictorDeleau I'm trying to pass compiler options to the Emscripten compiler: https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-s-option-value

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

If we look at the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#link-arg), there is both the `link-arg` option to pass a single argument and `link-args` to pass multiple arguments. Because `link-args` exist, and the doc specify that arguments must be separated by spaces, maybe you should use `... link-args="-s MINIMAL_RUNTIME=1"`, or even `... -C link-arg="-s" -C link-arg="MINIMAL_RUNTIME=1" ...` Haven't tried it though.

Second, there seem to be the old way of passing arguments to the linker of a specific compiler according to this [post](https://gregkatz.github.io/2017-05-20-rust-emscripten.html). You can create a wrapper around the `emcc` compiler by creating a file named `emcc_sdl` in your project folder which contains:

```
emcc "-s" "MINIMAL_RUNTIME=1" "-s" "ENVIRONMENT=web" "-s" "LEGACY_VM_SUPPORT=1" $@
```

Make it executable:

```
> chmod +x emcc_sdl
```

Create or edit the `.cargo/config` file and add:

```
[target.wasm32-unknown-emscripten]
linker = "/project_dir/project_name/emcc_sdl"

[target.asmjs-unknown-emscripten]
linker = "/project_dir/project_name/emcc_sdl"
```

You should be able to build using:

```
rustc demo.rs --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten -C opt-level=0 -o ../../build/bytecode/demo.asm.js
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten targets the emscripten compiler, which does recognise these flags.

Comment: Got it. I've updated my answer with two possible solutions